# Installing Cassandra 3.4 on Ubuntu with apt

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, apt

I'm doing: 
1.`$ echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/datastax-ddc 3.version_number main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list`
2. `$ curl -L https://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -`
3.    `$ sudo apt-get update`
4.    `$ sudo apt-get install datastax-ddc`
Terminal responses with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package datastax-ddc
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That error message means the datastax-ddc package is not being found within the repos in your sources.list files.

Things to try:

1. Is the package name correct? [Older documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installDeb.html) I found says you should use 'apt-get install dsc30' (for version 3.0 in this case). Are you using up-to-date documentation? Try an 'apt-get search dsc34' or 'apt-get search datastax' to see if there is another package available.
2. In the first line you echo `"deb http://debian.datastax.com/datastax-ddc 3.version_number main"`. It's a guess but should that "**3.version_number**" actually be **3.4** for your purposes? Once again, up-to-date documentation should sort that for you. If the repo address is correct you should see it listed in the output of the 'apt-get update' command. Check to make sure it appears there and doesn't throw an error (which might indicate the address is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

If you executed what you posted then on the first step you missed right version number. 
Try the following first command:

1.$ echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/datastax-ddc **3.4** main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list

The rest is as you did.